# Create a class for reading in files: creating an SQL api with distinct methods

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, oop, initialization

This question is more about how one uses OOP to read in databases. SQLite and sqlite3 are simply examples to work with, and are not the main thrust of the question:

I am creating a software package which allows users to query SQLite index files which have already been generated. It's basically syntactic to make it super user-friendly to query SQLite files indexed in a certain way, for a very particular case This should be quite straightforward, but I am somewhat confused how to "automatically" read in the SQLite

Here's an example (with pseudo-code):

```
import sqlite3

Class EasySQL:
    def __init__(self, filepath):
        self.filepath = filepath

    def connect(self, filepath):  ## perhaps this should be above in init?
        return sqlite3.connect(self.filepath)

    def query_indexA(self):
        ## query index A on SQLite3 connection
```

I would prefer the connection to the SQLite database to be "automatic" upon instantiation of the class:

```
### instantiate class
my_table1 = EasySQL("path/to/file")
```

At the moment, users one need to call the function `.connect()` after instantiation.

```
my_table = EasySQL("path/to/file")
the_object_to_do_queries = my_table.connect()

## now users can actually use this
the_object_to_do_queries.query_indexA()
```

This seems like bad form, and unnecessarily complicated.

How does one write the the initialization method to immediately create the SQLite3 connection?

Hopefully this question is clear. I am happy to edit if not.

Answer (score 1):

The main point here is that `EasySQL` should not return the connection (which makes it mostly useless) but use it internally by keeping a reference to it:

```
class EasySQL(object):
    def __init__(self, filepath):
        self._filepath = filepath
        self._db = sqlite3.connect(self.filepath)

    def close(self):
        if self._db:
            self._db.close()
            self._db = None

    def query_indexA(self):
        # XXX example implementation
        cursor = self._db.cursor()
        cursor.execute("some query here")
        return cursor.fetchall()
```